# PHP7 preg replace

Tags: php

I Want faster PHP7 alternative to filter variable to contain only numbers. 
For PHP56 I use this:

```
$string1 = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $string1);
```

part of my code:

```
if (preg_replace("/[^0-9,]/", "",$price) < (preg_replace("/[^0-9,]/", "",$special)+2)) {$special = false;}
```

But in PHP7 not working. It gives me error:

> A non well formed numeric value encountered ...

Тhe goal is in the given variable $string1 to rest only numbers.
Мay not be used preg_replace().  Preg_replace_callback() looks like a long and slow procedure.

Comment: "Not working" means what? You need to be more specific about the kind of output you're getting.

Comment: It seems to work fine: https://3v4l.org/6RveY

Comment: it brings me an error : Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Comment: That code will not produce that notice. Are you using `$string1` somewhere after this? Can you show an example of the input, and how you're using `$string1` after stripping out the non-numeric characters?

Comment: part of my code: if (preg_replace("/[^0-9,]/", "",$price) < (preg_replace("/[^0-9,]/", "",$special)+2)) {$special = false;}

Comment: You need to strip the commas from your numbers in your second example. You can't do math with numeric strings that contain commas.

Comment: The case is resolved.
The problem is in the comma.
Thanks.